# Kotlin get date for tomorrow only

Tags: date, kotlin

I need to display tomorrow's date only , l have this code and his working fine without problem . and he is give the current date for today. l want change this code to get the date for tomorrow but l dont know how !

```
  private fun date24hours(s: String): String? {
        try {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("EE, MMM d, yyy")
            val netDate = Date(s.toLong() * 1000)
            return sdf.format(netDate)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return e.toString()
```

Comment: Does the argument string hold seconds since the epoch? If you just want tomorrow’s date, this seems to be the detour.

Answer (score 3):

I might be late to the party, but this is what I found works for me

```
const val DATE_PATTERN = "MM/dd/yyyy"

internal fun getDateTomorrow(): String {
    val tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)
    return tomorrow.toString(DATE_PATTERN)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `Date` for this, but Java 8 `LocalDate` is a lot easier to work with:

```
// Set up our formatter with a custom pattern
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE, MMM d, yyy")

// Parse our string with our custom formatter
var parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(s, formatter)

// Simply plus 1 day to make it tomorrows date
parsedDate = parsedDate.plusDays(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
val tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
val formattedTomorrow = tomorrow.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE, MMM d, yyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
private fun date24hours(s: String): String? {
    val zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai")
    val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE, MMM d, uuuu", Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-OM"))
    val tomorrow = LocalDate.now(zone).plusDays(1)
    return tomorrow.format(dateFormatter)
}
```

I never tried writing Kotlin code before, so there’s probably one or more bugs, please bear with me.

In any case the date and time classes that you were using — `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`— had serious design problems and are now long outdated. I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, instead.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.